# HTTP PUT method confusing

Tags: php, rest, curl, restful-url

I want to learn how HTTP PUT method is used with PHP?

I googled at the web and found some tutorials about it with cURL.

But I dont know how to use it (Like REST API).

Comment: and what about http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: Do you want to receive or send the PUT request ?

Comment: i want to update or delete record at the same id. fox ex:http://somepage.com/users/1

Comment: If you know how to use GET or POST then its the same regarding usage. The difference between POST and PUT is that a PUT is usually used to get the information to update data server side and POST should send the informationn for creating new data.

Comment: @Daan the only proper way to **recieve** data is using GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $data = array("field" => "value");
    $ch = curl_init($yourUrl);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I woudl like to say that if url is same how can i differentiate PUT with GET? for ex:

Comment: Well then there's nothing that separates the requests, other than the method used, right? PUT is often used for updating resources on the server, GET usually for fetching data.